# How to define a menu with and without url arguments in hook_menu?

Tags: 7, hooks

```
 $items['jobs/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'custom_changes_jobs_interface_create_update',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page arguments' => array(1),
  );
```

I need to use `jobs` for POST request and `jobs/%` for put and delete request where the argument would be string but if its not passed I want to make sure it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Define both paths, jobs and jobs/%.

2) Define only the first path

```
$menu['jobs'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'my_page_callback',
  ...
```

Then make the argument optional:

```
function my_page_callback($job_id = FALSE) {
  ...
```

This callback will be called for both paths.